# Spring Cloud Stream Test Binder does not populate topic header

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

When a message is consumed from the Spring Cloud Stream test binder, the following header is not populated:

`kafka_receivedTopic`

But when I connect to an actual kafka broker, it's populated.

Is there a way to get the topic in the consumer.

My consumer:

```java
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<PlaneEvent>> planeEventConsumer() {
    return event -> {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test binder is exactly that; it is not a "test Kafka" binder; it is generic.

It is generally better to use the real binder for tests, with an embedded broker, or TestContainers.